# Bash: Loop through a directory, find files and print matching lines after concatenation with a word

Tags: bash

I'm working in a Sencha Touch project. It has js files, that contains lines like:

```
Ext.define('AssetMenuModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config:{    
        fields: ['code','name']
    }
});
```

We have to iterate the whole JS folder over the files with `*.js` extension. We can do this by:

`find ./js/common -type f -name "*.js"`

Find the line with `extend: 'Ext.data.Model'` and extract the part: `Ext.data.Model`.

Concatenate the extracted parts with `and include -namespace {Extracted_Part}`.

And ultimately print the output into a file or to console.

The output will be something like this

`and include -namespace Ext.data.Model and include -namespace Ext.Panel`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From where did `and include -namespace Ext.Panel` appear?

Comment: That will come by concatenating the extracted strings with `and include -namespace `

Comment: Both `Model` and `Panel`?

Comment: Yes. Both. Because we are dealing with multiple files. One file contains `extend: 'Ext.data.Model'`, another file contains `extend: Ext.Panel`. Another file may contain another statement. All those extracted strings are to be combined with the string `and include -namespace `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
for i in `find ./js/common -type f -name "*.js"`; do grep "extend: .*," $i | sed "s/.*'\(.*\)'.*/and include -namespace\1/" | tr '\n' ' ' ; done
```

Comment: Thanks devnull. It's working fine. Only I've changed the regExp as: `"extend:.*,"` as there are some instances with no space after `extend:`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that is not needed to check that `extend` line is inside `Ext.define` block. Otherwise the solution will be far more complex. This one reads every `js` file line by line and use a regular expression to find that line and do grouping to extract the string. I use hexadecimal digits to write single quotes (`\x27`) because the script is surrounded with them too:

```
perl -ne '
    if ( m/\A\s*(?i)extend\s*:\s*\x27([^\x27]*)\x27/ ) { 
        printf qq|and include -namespace %s |, $1;
    } 
    END { print "\n" }
' $(find ./js/common -type f -name "*.js")
```

In my test with two dummy `javascript` files created in a moment, yields:

```
and include -namespace Ext.data.Model and include -namespace Ext.Panel
```

Comment: This script is looping through only one directory. Doesn't enter the sub-directories.

Comment: @ArnabDas: Edited. I substituted `*.js` with the `find` command.